# Java applet sound issues, sound continues on close, and I can't sign the sound files

Tags: java, audio, applet, code-signing

So I was working on a mini game, and for the first time I added sound to my game, but I ran into two issues, the first is that when I load the applet up in my browser, and I close the tab when I'm done, the background music continues to play for a bit. I'm using this to play the background:

```
AudioClip audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "bg.wav");
audioClip.loop();
```

And that's inside the init()

My second problem is that whenever I start the applet, it brings up that warning saying there is a mixture of signed and unsigned code, and that it could be unsafe. I've never gotten that before, so I assume it's the sound files, what can I do about that?

http://www.FreeMinecraftHost.com/ParticleDefender is where the applet is hosted if you would like to see the message it brings up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning I got did not say anything about 'mixing signed & unsigned code', but I refused the 'allow trusted code' dialog to check that the applet will work in a sand-box.  It seems to work just fine, I could move left & right, shoot, destroy enemies, be destroyed by them, hear the (v. loud) music track, and restart the game.

Since the applet element indicates only a single Jar, and the main class is in that Jar, I cannot understand how you could get a message like you saw.  Nevertheless, the solution to not get *any* prompts seems obvious.

**Don't sign the Jar!**

Comment: don't sign the jar?! I thought you always had to sign the jar?

Comment: I did! That fixed the signing issue! As for the Sound issue, I added the destroy() method and stoped the sound clip, but still didnt work

Comment: The sound issue was in the top part of my question :) Basically the sound plays even after you close out of the applet, and I added a destroy() method that does audioClip.stop(); So I don't know why

Comment: *"The sound issue was in the top part of my question"*  Yes, and my first comment was in reply to the question.  Did you miss it?  OTOH I note you did not accept my answer or respond to the comment, so it seems you are ignoring anything you do not want to hear, and I am wasting my time.

Comment: I didn't see that comment! I'm sorry! I'll post another question thank  you :)

Comment: *"I'll post another question"*  Good move.  :)

Answer (score 0):

That guy was a jerk messed up my answer (like I said it's been years)

Anyways, Here is my audio handler, on closer inspection I relized that in my program I was looping the background music, about a 1 min audio file. The audio clip would be interuped on a win/loose/or exit by a seperate very short clip and the audio would self terminate. You could kill your music this way just by playing a short clip of nothing or some exit sound.

By the way what I said in my first answer was not a guess we really did have to do that back then.

```
private void musicHandler(int musicFunction)
 {
      for( int counter =0; counter < 3; counter++)
      audioClip[counter].stop();
        if(musicFunction == 0)
            audioClip[musicFunction].loop();
        else
             audioClip[musicFunction].play();

  }
 AudioClip audioClip[] = new AudioClip[10]; 
 private void musicLoader()
  {
    try
      {
        URL baseURL = new URL("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/");
        URL completeURL = new URL(baseURL, "game.wav");
        audioClip[0] = Applet.newAudioClip(completeURL);
        completeURL = new URL(baseURL, "TAPS.WAV");
        audioClip[1] = Applet.newAudioClip(completeURL);
        completeURL = new URL(baseURL, "YEAH.WAV");
        audioClip[2] = Applet.newAudioClip(completeURL); 
        audioClip[0].loop();
       }
     catch (MalformedURLException exception) {}

     }
```

Comment: *"That guy was a jerk messed up my answer"*  You are the only one that contributed to your answer.  So you are a jerk?